# Accessing a parent model attribute within Django template

Tags: python, html, django, view, model

I have an app that has a list of projects, and each project has a number of posts, and when you click on a project, it shows all of the posts in that project, but I can't figure out how to make it display what project the user is currently on, [sample of it not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GCIp.png) It should say "Posts for project 1" for example. Here is the relevant code of what I have so far.

```
    <h1 class="mb-3">Posts for {{ post.project.title }}</h1>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <article class="media content-section">
            <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
            <div class="media-body">
                <div class="article-metadata">
                    <a class="mr-2">{{ post.author }}</a>
                    <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
                </div>
                <h2><a class="article-title">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
                <p class="article-content">{{ post.description }}</p>
            </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
```

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('project-detail', kwargs = {'pk': self.pk})

    class Post(models.Model):

    def get_default_action_status():
        return Project.objects.get(title="bruh")
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts', default=get_sentinel_exam_id)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    LOW = '!'
    MED = '!!'
    HIGH = '!!!'
    
    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = [
        (LOW, '!'),
        (MED, '!!'),
        (HIGH, '!!!'),
    ]
    severity = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
        default=LOW,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs = {'pk': self.pk})
```

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('', ProjectListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserProjectListView.as_view(), name='user-projects'),
    path('project/<str:title>', ProjectPostListView.as_view(), name='project-posts'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='project-detail'),
    path('post/new/', ProjectCreateView.as_view(), name='project-create'),
    
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', ProjectUpdateView.as_view(), name='project-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', ProjectDeleteView.as_view(), name='project-delete'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='blog-about'),
    ]
```

```
class ProjectPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/project_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 10
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        project = get_object_or_404(Project, title=self.kwargs.get('title'))
        return Post.objects.filter(project=project).order_by('-date_posted')
```

Apologies if some of that code wasn't needed, I am new to Django.

Comment: You can implement it in various ways and it depends how you want to accomplish this. If you don't want to reload page once the user selects the field then you have to use `ajax` call in your template. If you are comfortable with reload page on user selection then you can make it using your code only.

Comment: I don't think I explained my problem very well, I am asking how do I get the title of the project for my posts within the html for the list of posts

Comment: I was thinking of maybe trying use a get_object_or_404 to get the project that way, but I'm not sure how to implement that within my views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by making the model of "ProjectPostListView" into a Project, and then changing that to a DetailView so I could just use all of the post objects associated with that project.